# tikz-timing: How to draw a clock with slope and arrows

Tags: arrows, tikz-timing

I need a clock signal with a slope, therefore I can't use the timing character 'C' (no slope). Ideally I'd just use the LH combination as in the code below, but but these characters don't admit arrows.
I've spend quite sometime trying to find a solution, I'd appreciate any help.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz-timing}
\usepackage[active, tightpage, psfixbb]{preview}

\usetikzlibrary{arrows}
\usetikztiminglibrary{clockarrows, nicetabs}

\PreviewEnvironment{pgfpicture}

\setlength\PreviewBorder{5pt}

\begin{document}
  \begin{tikztimingtable}[%
    scale = 1.5,
    timing/.cd,
    lslope = 0.3,
    c/rising arrows,
    c/arrow pos = 0.7,
    c/arrow tip = stealth'
    ]

    CK1 &    0.8H 2{4L4H} ;\\   
    CK2 &  H 4{4C};\\
  \end{tikztimingtable}
\end{document}
```

[image: clock like signal that needs rising-edge arrows]

Answer (score 0):

My solution to this same problem works like this:

- Include `\usetikztiminglibrary{advnodes}`
- You can then name the transitions with N.  For instance, L N(myTransition) H
- Once you name a transition, you have named coordinates for the relevant points in that transition, which can be seen in the tikz-timing manual
- In your case, to draw an arrow, in tne extracode section, all you have to do is: `\draw[->] (myTransition.low) -- (myTransition.high)`;